# In tabulator, how do you set cell level configuration for Select editor?

Tags: jquery, html-table, tabulator

I have a select editor for one of my columns in tabulator table. However, I want to specifically disable the editor for one of my cells in the same column. Is there any configuration for it?

```
columns: [
              { title: "name", field: "name" },
              { title: "date", field: "gender" },
              {title: "gender", editor: "select", editorParams: {
                        values: gender
                         }
               }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are specifically wanting to block the edit under circumstances then you can pass a callback to the ***editable*** function that should return `true` when a cell is editable and `false` when a cell is not

```
var editCheck = function(cell){
    //cell - the cell component for the editable cell

    //get row data
    var data = cell.getRow().getData();

    return data.age > 18; // only allow the name cell to be edited if the age is over 18
}

//in your column definition for the column
{title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"input", editable:editCheck}
```

If you more specifically want to change the params passed into the editor per cell, then you can pass a function to the ***editorParams*** column definition property that should return the params object, this function is called just before the editor is created

```
//define lookup function
function paramLookup(cell){
    //cell - the cell component

    //do some processing and return the param object
    return {param1:"green"};
}

//column definition
{title:"Rating", field:"rating", editor:"star", editorParams:paramLookup}
```

Details on all edit functionality can be found in the [Editing Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/edit)